# Strange behaviour on evil-delete

Tags: key-bindings, evil

When I use Emacs with Evil mode for some time, I sometimes get to a point, where I have no choice to what I want to delete when pressing `d` (or calling `evil-delete`). The current line gets deleted without that I have pressed `d` for the line a second time. Same behavior is shown when pressing `c` or calling `evil-change`. Both are acting like having pressed `dd` or `cd` instead.
Certainly I have accidentally pressed some keyboard shortcuts to activate this mapping, but I have no clue how to find out what is happening there. At the moment my only chance is to restart Emacs to get back to normal behavior. If I only knew what happens, maybe I would be able to switch back to normal behavior without restarting Emacs.

Comment: This sounds as if you have accidentally enabled capslock. You should be able to verify this with `F1 l`. The other option of debugging is instrumenting the relevant functions to log their internal state and inspect the log whenever running into that situation.

Comment: @wasamasa I am sure, that I have not enabled capslock. Than even other keys would behave different from normal, which is not the case. Could you explain, how to log state in the relevant functions? I assume I have to edit the evil source for that?

Comment: This happens to me in Spacemacs (develop branch) now and then. I have capslock remapped to control, so @wasamasa's hypothesis can't be correct. `F1 l` switches me to a different frame. The only solution I have found is to quit and restart emacs.

Answer (score 16):

I noticed the <kbd>d</kbd> key deleting a line on a single press as well. I am using Spacemacs v0.300.0@26.1 on the develop branch. I do not know if this is your case, but I had an incomplete search in progress.

Steps to reproduce:

1. In command mode, initiate a search by pressing the <kbd>/</kbd> key
2. With the mouse, click on any text in your buffer
3. Press the <kbd>d</kbd> key a single time and a line will be deleted

Steps to resolve:

1. With the mouse, click on your incomplete search
2. Either cancel the search by pressing the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key until the search is cleared OR complete the search by pressing the <kbd>RET</kbd> key
3. The behavior of the <kbd>d</kbd> key should return to normal (at least it did for me)

**Update 2019-05-14**
I stumbled upon a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024055) from @trey-jackson. For spacemacs users, plunking Trey's solution:

```lisp
(defun stop-using-minibuffer ()
    "kill the minibuffer"
    (when (and (>= (recursion-depth) 1) (active-minibuffer-window))
      (abort-recursive-edit)))

(add-hook 'mouse-leave-buffer-hook 'stop-using-minibuffer)
```

in `.spacemacs` under `dotspacemacs/user-config` seems to resolve the problem.

Comment: Good catch! This appears to boil down to an unhandled case in `evil-operator-range` where it falls back to regular motions. Now, if you have any ideas how to detect this state, that would be nice.

Comment: Thanks @wasamasa, one work-around is to stop using the mouse!  I am pretty new to emacs, so delving into evil code is beyond me right now. Is [this](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil) the right place to raise an issue?

Comment: I created an account to upvote you. thought i was crazy

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: I was using `(evil-set-undo-system 'undo-tree)`, and getting `"Re-entering top level after C stack overflow"` errors frequently when saving large files with long undo-tree histories. When I stopped using undo-tree I stopped getting those errors, and also stopped getting the "pressing `d` a single time deletes the whole line as if I pressed `dd`" behavior.